# How to catch a color from clipboard in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, shortcuts, hex

I'm a huge fan of shortcuts that makes my work easier. I have a set of little tricks in my PS that make my work blazing fast, today I was thinking if there is a possibility to put a copied color in HEX e.g. example i opened Color Picker and copied "#761111" to clipboard now I want to apply it to a shape without opening it's color picker.

Maybe some kind of action, script or whatever that will set that HEX as my foreground or background color or put it directly to a shape.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't exist that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you create a color from the color picker, why not save it as a swatch for easy selection? From there you can 1-click choose the color of your shape, if it is not already set as the foreground color.

Also, If you set your color palette to 'web color sliders' you can easily type in your hex there, then create a swatch.

Swatches are reusable which could save a lot of time recreating colors. If you're working with a lot of colors and don't want too many swatches, you could probably also create an action (if not script) that creates the swatch, then shape, applying that color, then deleting the swatch.